# Given a norm of an Eisenstein integer how do we find this integer?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Say we are given the norm of an Eisenstein integer $N(f)=7$. How do we actually find the integer?

The norm for any Eisenstein integer is defined as 
$$N(f)=(a+b\epsilon)(a+b\bar\epsilon)=a^2-ab+b^2$$ where $\epsilon=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}$

Is there any algorithm for going ''backwards''?

Thanks

Comment: Except if the norm is $0$, there are several Eisenstein integers with that norm. Would any of these suffice, or are you looking for a specific one?

Comment: I am trying to find out how to determine these: $f=2+3\epsilon$, $f=3+2\epsilon$ and $f=3+\epsilon$. All of them have norm 7.

Comment: Well, you can look at $$(2a-b)^2 + 3b^2 = 28,$$ which gives you the options $b = \pm 1,\,\pm 2,\,\pm 3$. The corresponding values for $2a-b$ are $\pm 5,\, \pm 4, \, \pm 1$. Then combine.

Comment: @DanielFischer where did you get $(2a-b)^2+3b^2=28$ from?

Comment: You start with $a^2 - ab + b^2 = 7$. Multiply by $4$, get $4a^2 - 4ab + b^2 + 3b^2 = 28$. I find it easier to work with it in that form.

Comment: Ah yes, brilliant. Thank you